# nltk: Unable to download package punkt while building docker

Tags: python, docker, proxy, dockerfile, nltk

I am running this behind corportate proxy
Used the command: **RUN python -m nltk.downloader punkt**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py:127: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))

[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or
[nltk_data]     service not known>
Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 2533, in <module>
    rv = downloader.download(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 790, in download
    choice = input().strip()

EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only experienced this error in PyCharm. When I built my container on the command line using `docker build . -t relish/my_image`, the error didn't happen and my PyCharm build started working too.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to pass the proxy configuration into your container(s) during docker build, [see](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg). This only works if nltk evaluates those standard environment variables, though.

```
docker build \
  --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://10.20.30.2:1234 \
  --build-arg FTP_PROXY=http://40.50.60.5:4567 \
  .
```

Comment: I gave proxy directly to nltk by adding the line "import nltk; nltk.set_proxy('<Proxy>'), nltk.download('words')" and it worked